# < is being converted into &lt; in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using syntax highlighter to show code preview. But all '<' is being converted into `&lt;`. Some suggest to filter the content and replace '&lt' with <. But when I want to show `&lt;` indeed what should I do then? Any idea?

N.B: I am using Gutenburge Editor. When I go to code view or text view and manually change `&lt;` to < then it is set. and Update several times also keep < as <.

Comment: You should use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` to prevent the text from being interpreted as html - for example if you want to show `<a href=....>...</a>` as text, not to make it an actual link. Take a look at HTML Entities - this will cover some point about the other cases when certain charters may be changed.

Comment: but > is okay. why only < is being converted?

Comment: `>` is the **closing** tag in html, just by itself ( without the **opening** one `<`) it won't be interpreted.